# unable to connect to GCP running Airflow locally on docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am running Airflow locally on docker, trying to connect to google cloud via Admin>Connections. when I try and test connection , i see the below error
"The `keyfile_dict`, `key_path`, and `key_secret_name` fields are all mutually exclusive. Please provide only one value." Unsure on what is missing. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: From your above screenshot, I can see you are updating an existing connection. your connection already has Keyfile JSON but is not visible while editing the connection form and now you are trying to add Keyfile Path (a Possibility). A quick test you can do is to try to create a connection with a new connection id

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Create a connection with "google_cloud_default" connection id
- Connection Type: Google Cloud
- Create a service account with bigquery permissions (if you don't have yet)
- Download the JSON service account.
- Copy the JSON content and paste in KeyFileJSON field.

Another solution:

- Create an environment variable in your docker file (or docker-compose) called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that point to the service account json (You have to mount a volume pointing to the folder where the service account json is located).
- Create a connection with "google_cloud_default" connection id and Google Cloud connection type.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you , i was able to create a new connection with the above instructions and it worked , thank you !